# Sending email SMTP via GMAIL (OAUTH2 and JavaMail)

Tags: oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail

I'm using a web application through which I'm sending an email.
The SMTP host is GMAIL.
I'm using Java 1.8 and JavaMail 1.6.2.

Is there any alternative to the code written below? (credits: https://hellokoding.com/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-java-mail-api-and-oauth-2-authorization/)

```
void sendMail(String smtpServerHost, String smtpServerPort,  String smtpUserName, String smtpUserAccessToken, String fromUserEmail, String fromUserFullName, String toEmail, String subject, String body) {
    try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpServerPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromUserEmail, fromUserFullName));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setContent(body, "text/html");

        SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, null);
        transport.connect(smtpServerHost, smtpUserName, null);
        transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(BASE64EncoderStream.encode(String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", smtpUserName, smtpUserAccessToken).getBytes())), 235);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

Specifically I'm very confused about these two issues:

1. is the following line truly the only way to set the access token in the Transport?

**transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(BASE64EncoderStream.encode(String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", smtpUserName, smtpUserAccessToken).getBytes())), 235);**

I've been searching throughout the web but I don't seem to find an answer, basically because every other way I've attempted has resulted in NO success.

2. Is it true that Google has not (yet) implemented a CLIENT credentials grant type?
   How else could I send emails through my web application without the user interaction (which I don't have)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

//TLS and OAuth2

String address = "my.smtpserver.com";
Integer port = 587;
String user = "my_username";
String accesstoken = "my_accesstoken";
String sender = "me@mycompany.com";
String recipients = "you@yourcompany.com;someone@theircompany.com";
String subject = "Test";
String body = "This is a test.";

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", address);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port.toString());
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
properties.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
session.setDebug(true);

MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
String s = recipients.replace(';', ',');
mimeMessage.addRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, 
InternetAddress.parse(s));
mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);

MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();

MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
mimeBodyPart.setText(body);
mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultipart);

Transport transport = session.getTransport();

transport.connect(user, accesstoken);       
transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());

transport.close();

session = null;
```

Comment: I'm using Jakarta Mail 1.6.7 and AdoptOpen JDK 8.0.272.

Comment: Also, I couldn't use Jakarta Mail 2.x with JRE 8 because in JRE 8, the Jakarta Activation classes are in package javax.activation.  Jakarta Mail 2.x assumes that the package is jakarta.activation, which causes a NoClassDefFound error when mixed with JRE 8.  I don't know what version of the JRE has the repackaged Jakarta Activation classes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)